# store id's in the backend through URL automatically in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have one view candidates page in my application..in that i gave one button called schedule..once user click on the button the page will redirect to selection process form with candidate_id and user_id in the URL..in the view candidates page i have user_id..

And i have one schedule table in my backend..in that table i have candidate_id & user_id ..so what i want to do is when user redirect to selection form and insert values in form and after submit.. i want to store that candidate_id and user_id  back end automatically..

here is my button code:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/Candidate/candidate_process/<?php echo $idata->candidate_id; ?>/<?php echo $idata->user_id; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Schedule Interview</a></td>
```

Can anyone help me..How to do this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think you should put question mark after url and Ampersand after first parameter

Comment: how should we put when i tried i got some error...can you please explain how can we put..

Comment: <td><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/Candidate/candidate_process/   ?    candidate=  <?php echo $idata->candidate_id; ?>    &         user =     <?php echo $idata->user_id; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Schedule Interview</a></td>

Comment: read it through

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%20' at line 1

Comment: like www.google.com ? candidate = <?php echo $idata->candidate_id; ?>  &   user = <?php echo $idata->user_id; ?>

Comment: yeah. it's coming error..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136805/discussion-between-janatbek-sharsheyev-and-m5533).

Comment: You need to use sessions for this, I can forge/fake the data in the url and hidden fields very easily.

Comment: @qwertzman yup..i did it.thanks for reply..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Button:

```
  <td><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/Candidate/candidate_process/<?php echo $idata->candidate_id; ?>/ <?php echo $idata->user_id; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Button</a></td>
```

Controller:

```
function candidate_process($candidateid,$userid)
```

{

$data['getCandidate'] =                $this->CandidateModel->get_candidate_detail($candidateid);

}

Model:

```
function get_candidate_detail($candidateid)
```

{

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM candidates_details WHERE candidate_id=$candidateid");
if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
{
    return $q->row_array();
} 
else 
{
    return '';
}
```

}

view:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="candidate_id" value="<?php echo $getCandidate['candidate_id']; ?>">

          <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $getCandidate['user_id']; ?>">
```